# Set mobile data enabled via android code on switch button

Tags: android, performance, system-calls

I tried the following method:

```
public void mobiledataenable(boolean enabled) {

    try {
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Added the following permissions:

```
**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"**
```

And called it with `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Still not getting Internet On.

I want this code or any other code to work for API 19 and above.

Comment: You cannot turn on mobile data through application code. This code only works with older(much older) versions of android(unless the device is rooted).

Comment: thanks. I navigated user to settings for data Switching